# Combine 2 plots (ggplot) but use one legend and colour scheme

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have created 2 plots and combined them as seen below but i now wish to plot this with one legend and the same colour scheme for both plots, does anyone know what changes i need to make this?

code used to create plots

```
#plotting actual from 1998-2020
mapplot_temp = ggplot(map_preds20, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
 geom_polygon(aes(fill = GDP_pdiff), colour = "black")
mapplot1 = mapplot_temp + scale_fill_gradient(name = 'GDP per capita change %', low = 
'red', high = 'yellow', na.value = 'grey') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20, face = "bold"))

#plotting predicted from 2021-2040
mapplot_temp2 = ggplot(map_preds40, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = GDP_pdiff), colour = "black")
mapplot2 = mapplot_temp2 + scale_fill_gradient(name = 'GDP per capita change % ($)', low = 'red', high = 'yellow', na.value = 'grey') +
  ggtitle('Predicted GDP per capita change') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20, face = "bold"))

#combine plots with one legend and same colour scheme
mapplot1 + mapplot2
```

plot

[image]

Comment: Set the same `limits` in your `scale_fill_gradient` (say `limits = c(-20, 5)` in each plot). In the first plot, add the line `guides(fill = guide_none())`. Then simply `p1 + p2` should give you want you want. If you are still stuck after this, please post a reproducible example.

Comment: @AllanCameron Yeh thats perfect now. Is there anyway the colouring can be changed so it changes colour in smaller incriments, as a lot of my values are between +2 and -5 its very yellow. I tried ColorBrewer but thats just more of a palette change

Comment: you could try `scale_fill_gradientn`, which accepts a whole vector of colors, as well as the ability to specify where on the range each is placed.